# How to execute a method remotely on a jar file

Tags: java, reflection, jar, execution

I have an application whose purpose is to call the same particular method in the same class in lots of different jar files spread across a file system and receive back a result. So I can be guaranteed that a certain class and method will exist in a jar file.

I know where each jar file is located. Its quite easy for me to instantiate the class via reflection and call the method in that manner.

My problem is that I have many of these jar files. And if I use the above approach to call into each jar, I'm concerned that the memory consumption of my application will increase dramatically as I will have to load the entire jar file for each call.

Is there any way I can call these jars files other than reflection? System calls wont work as I need to receive back a value.

much appreciated...

Comment: Out of interest, how do you load the same class from different jar files in your code?

Comment: Did You consider using separate ClassLoaders and disposing it at the end? I thought that's the way the containers do their .jar management (Tomcat).

Comment: @DaveHowes - I just create a local URLClassloader which contains the URL to the jar file I'm interested in. I then use Class.ForName() etc.

Comment: @Rekin - Yes, I use local URLClassloader which go out of scope when the call is done. However at this point, the jar I'm interested in has been loaded. Will it still remain in memory?

Comment: @Belltower: AFAIK the class definitions go straight to perm gen space, which is very rarely swept out, but nonetheless is sometimes. When nothing is referencing them, then there's no reason to keep them. Maybe Jochen could correct me on this.

Comment: @Rekin - yes this is my concern. What will happen to perm gen space over a period of time...

Answer (score 3):

You might run into problems with perm space, but this can be increased with `-XX:MaxPermSize=`
parameter.

Make sure you use a separate URLClassLoader for each JAR file and don't hold onto them so they can get GCd.
Load the JAR file through the new URLClassLoader, then use Class.forName() to load.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, thats pretty much how I'm doing it at the moment. I create a local URLClassLoader which contains the path to jar file I'm interested in. Then I use class.FoName() etc. Just question though, once the jar file is loaded via the ClassLoader, will it remain in memory even after the ClassLoader has been GC'd?

Comment: there used to be issues around open files and URLClassLoaders. If you have the luxury to go with an early Java 7 release, it has a new close() method on URLClassLoaders.

Comment: You have to consider the caching mechanism in JVM too. I guess there is no way disable caching in URLClassLoader caching.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this pseudocode:

```
foreach jf : myJarFiles
  jcl = new JarClassLoader(jf);
  Class.forName(myClassName);
  m = MyClass.getMethod(...);
  m.invoke(...);
```

Comment: yes thats pretty much how I do it. Its just the jar management aspect I'm worried about. Once the local classloader has gone out of scope, I want the jar file, which will have been loaded into memory, to be released. Otherwise I'm concerned about the size of the memory after repeated calls to load jar files.

Comment: @belltower: note that the memory usage of the JVM will increase as you load each JAR file but as long as you use a separate classloader for each one then the garbage collector will free up memory *when needed*, assuming you don't retain unneeded references.